# How do I grab the entire table off a website and export it into excel

Tags: python, excel, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to grab the entire table from the website:

http://eweb.washco.utah.gov:8080/recorder/taxweb/account.jsp?accountNum=0972029

note: when you first click on the link, it will have you click a public login button. I have already created the bot to login and search through the website so, that is not the issue. I just need it to get the table off of the end result page that is linked above

table HTML: table class="AccountSummary"

and export it into an excel file.

I have tried a few methods but can't seem to get it working.

```
url=urllib.request.urlopen("http://eweb.washco.utah.gov:8080/recorder/taxweb/account.jsp?accountNum=0972029")
s = url.read()
html = etree.HTML(s)
tr_nodes = html.xpath(AccountSummary)
header = [i[0].text for i in tr_nodes[0].xpath("th")]

td_content = [[td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')] for tr in tr_nodes[1:]]
ff = open("output.csv", "w")
ff.write(str(s))
ff.close()
```

[CLICK: HTML Table that I am trying to export into excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trIRt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When I first clicked on your link, I had to click on a "public login" button first before I got to the table with my browser. Therefore I am guessing that table isnt even rendering when you use urllib.request.urlopen etc.

Comment: Yes, I have coded a bot that logins in and then searches. The website asks you to log in for the first time using it. The trouble I am having is after I have logged in and got to the account that was searched and grabbing that table from the account summary page.

Comment: Also, that isn't the issue cause I have it show my the current URL when it gets to the page with the table to make sure that it got to where I need the table from.